# Можно ли вызвать метода класса без вызова конструктора?

Tags: php

Можно ли вызвать метода класса без вызова конструктора?

**UPD1**

Пытаюсь сделать следующее:

```
 $this->CI->load->library('countrylang');
 $this->CI->countrylang->_getSux(); Где _getSux() статический метод
```

Comment: Конструктор не обязателен, в принципе.

Comment: Конструктор не обязателен, в принципе. - не совсем верное утверждение. Даже если явно в коде не написать код создания объекта - то при создании все равно будет вызван конструктор. Другое дело, что он пустой от клиентского кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

статистические методы класса

```
static
```

**UPD1**

Где _getSux() статический метод - Метод какого класса?

Comment: Добавлю пять копеек - [Ключевое слово "static"][1]


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: Тогда получается в стат.методы нет доступа к $this методам класса

Comment: Т.е. как получить доступ к переменной public $test; если она не статическая

Comment: ну да, потому как ты не создаешь объект. Если нужен $this - тогда только через конструктор. Есть также и статистические переменные класса - которые общие для все созданных на его основе объектов. Их ты можешь использовать в статистических методах.

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, $this - относится к объекту, а содержимое свойств объектов одного класса может быть разное. static переменная относится к классу, поэтому содержимое static переменной одинаковое для всех объектов одного класса. Вывод: в обычных методах можно юзать self::$var, а в статических нельзя $this->var

Comment: А если хочу вызвать статическую переменную из другого класса - как быть?

Comment: ДА еще почитайте тут http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php - чтоб потом на грабли не наступать -это про разницу self:: и static:: - Позднее статическое связывание.